# Code proper query for generated registration form

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a project wherein the registration form is made depending on the database fields like this:

```
function generateForm() {

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'toor', 'hybrid_offline_reg');
    $query = $db->query('DESCRIBE `' . $_SESSION['tableName'] .'`');
    $fields = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $fields[] = $row['Field'];
        $types[] = $row['Type'];
    }

    echo "<form method='post' action='successpage.php' align='center'>
    <table align='center'>";

    foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
        $type = $types[$key];

        echo "<tr>";

        switch ($field) {
            case "FNAME":
                echo "<td>First Name</td><td>:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='FNAME' size=30></td>";
                break;

            case "MNAME":
                echo "<td>Middle Name</td><td>:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='MNAME' size=30></td>";
                break;

            case "LNAME":
                echo "<td>Last Name</td><td>:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='LNAME' size=30></td>";
                break;

            echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submitForm' value=' Submit '>
    <input type='reset' name='resetForm' value=' Clear '>
    </form>";
```

And on the **successpage.php**, this is what it looks like so far:

```
session_start();
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'toor', 'hybrid_offline_reg');
    $query = $db->query('DESCRIBE `' . $_SESSION['tableName'] .'`');
    //$fields = array();

    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $_SESSION['tableName'] . "`(";

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $f = $row['Field'];

        switch ($f) {

            case "USER_ID":
            case "DATE_CREATED": break;

            default:
                $insert_sql .= "`$f`,";
                break;
        }
    }

    $insert_sql = substr_replace($insert_sql, "", -1);
    $insert_sql .= ") VALUES (";


    $query = $db->query('DESCRIBE `' . $_SESSION['tableName'] .'`');
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i = $row['Field'];

        switch ($i) {

            case "USER_ID":
            case "DATE_CREATED": break;

            default:
                $insert_sql .= '`$_POST["' . $i . '"]`,' ;
                break;
        }
    }

    $insert_sql = substr_replace($insert_sql, "", -1);
    $insert_sql .= ")";

    $res = mysql_query($insert_sql);
    echo "Successfully registered!";
```

But obviously, the `$insert_sql .= '$_POST["' . $i . '"],' ;` isn't correct since the `$_POST` shouldn't be a string because I am trying to get its value. But I am also trying to depend the name of the `$_POST` from `$i`.

Help, anyone? D: Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$insert_sql .= '`$_POST["' . $i . '"]`,' ;
```

To this:

```
$insert_sql .= '`'. mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[$i]) .'`,';
```

You already know how to concatenate strings in PHP, since you're doing it in that line. You just need to take the `$_POST` part out of the string itself.

Also, read up on SQL injection. You shouldn't take raw data from user input and use it in a query without first sanitizing it. Hence, I added `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

One more thing...at the end there, it looks like you're calling `mysql_query()`. Think you meant `mysqli_query()` there, no? Or perhaps `$db->query()`?

Comment: I used `$insert_sql .= "'". mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[$i]) ."',";` since "`" wasn't accepted and it requires the two parameters. Oh, and the query part was fixed as well. Thank you so much for your help, and yes, I will read up on SQL injection. :)